# How to handle jpa entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table client and from retrieving results I use this way

```
public ClientParent getClient(Long clientId,Long parentId){
        String queryString="SELECT cp FROM Client cp where cp.cid.id=:clientId " +
                "and cp.pid.id=:parentId  ";        
        Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);   
        query.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
        return (ClientParent)query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

This is the DAO method.

Actually for getting client at 1st control goes to controller class then to service and then DAO class

Now lets say that the client table is empty so in this case `return (ClientParent)query.getSingleResult();` will throw me error.

I can handle this in by wrting in try catch block in service class as well as in controller class.But wanted to know if I can do with out throwing any exception.I mean do I have change the query or what should I return so that it will never throw exception even if the table is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the getResultList() method

```
public ClientParent getClient(Long clientId,Long parentId){
        String queryString="SELECT cp FROM Client cp where cp.cid.id=:clientId " +
                "and cp.pid.id=:parentId  ";        
        Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);   
        query.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
        List<ClientParent> result = query.getResultList();
        if (result != null && result.size() >0){
            return result.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
       }
    }
```

Comment: so if the table is emtpy then it will return null.I calling the methods of ClientParent in service class `ClientParent cp=clientDaoImpl.getClientParent(clientId, parentId);
  cp.setDeleted(true);
  entityManagerUtil.update(cp);` so as cp will be null for empty table so in the service class also it throw me error

Comment: What will you do if you do not find an object? Will you create a new one? you can use an `if (cp != null)` in your service.

Comment: also result.size() returns int so can we do result.size() != null

Comment: @rocking sorry my fault. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: query.getSingleResult(); will give me only one record but if I do your way then wont it give me all the records?

Comment: No. This gives you only the first record: `result.get(0);`

Comment: As getSingleResult will also fail if you get more than two rows with a NonUniqueException you should check that the list size is exactly 1 and not just bigger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to surround your code with `try-catch` block. So will sure that the data is correct.

```
try {
   // ... your code goes here
   // getSingleResult()
   return XXX;
} catch(NonUniqueResultException e) {
    // here you know there is some bad data 
    // so you can ignore it or do something 
} catch(NoResultException e){ 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ohh yes I have this try -catch block in all my methods